# in defining a function in Dart, how to set an argument's default to { }, ie, an empty Map?

Tags: function, dart, default

love how `Dart` treats function arguments, but cannot accomplish what should be a simple task:

```
  void func( String arg1, [ Map args = {} ] ) {
    ...
  }
```

get the error

```
  expression is not a valid compile-time constant
```

have tried `new Map()` for example, with same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default value must be a compile time constant, so 'const {}' will keep the compiler happy, but possibly not your function.

If you want a new modifiable map for each call, you can't use a default value on the function parameter. That same value is used for every call to the function, so you can't get a new value for each call that way.
To create a new object each time the function is called, you have to do it in the function itself. The typical way is:

```dart
void func(String arg1, [Map args]) {
  if (args == null) args = {};
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You have to use the `const` keyword :

```dart
void func( String arg1, [ Map args = const {} ] ) {
  ...
}
```

Warning : if you try to modify the default `args` you will get :

> Unsupported operation: Cannot set value in unmodifiable Map

Comment: would this allow me to change `args` in the body of the function, eg, `args['me']='myself';`

Comment: no, you will get a runtime error : Unsupported operation: Cannot set value in unmodifiable Map